# CakePHP change the form of the serialized array

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I have an array, which I get in JSON format using /customers.json (here a I get the list of all the customer). I get the customers this way:

```
$customers = $this->Customer->find('all');
```

That's how I am serializing the data in JSON format.

```
$this->set(array('customers' => $customers, '_serialize' => array('customers')));
```

The data in browser looks so:

```
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "Customer": {
                "number": "17",
                "address": "Frau",
                "title": "",
                "company": "",
                "street": "Altk\u00f6nigstr. 17",
                "street2": "",
                "zip": "60385",
                "city": "Frankfurt am Main",
                "phone": "",
                "fax": "",
                "comment": "",
                "company_name": "Altmeier, Gerda",
                "bankaccount_holder": "Altmeier, Gerda",
                "bankaccount_holder_extra": false
            }
        },
        {
            "Customer": {
                "number": "33",
                "address": "Herr",
                "title": "",
                "company": "",
                "street": "Thewalt-Str. 22",
                "street2": "",
                "zip": "60385",
                "city": "Frankfurt am Main",
                "phone": "",
                "fax": "",
                "comment": "",
                "company_name": "Bach, J\u00fcrgen",
                "bankaccount_holder": "Bach, J\u00fcrgen",
                "bankaccount_holder_extra": false
            }
        },
        {
```

but I need the data to be outputed in the next way:

```
[{
        "number" : "3",
        "address" : "",
        "title" : "",
        "company" : "",
        "street" : "",
        "street2" : "",
        "zip" : "89073",
        "city" : "Ulm",
        "phone" : "",
        "fax" : "",
        "comment" : "",
        "company_name" : "Born, Lionel",
        "bankaccount_holder" : "Born, Lionel",
        "bankaccount_holder_extra" : false
    }, {
        "number" : "1",
        "address" : "Herr",
        "title" : "",
        "company" : "",
        "street" : "Marienburgstraße",
        "street2" : "",
        "zip" : "64297",
        "city" : "Darmstadt",
        "phone" : "",
        "fax" : "",
        "comment" : "",
        "company_name" : "Myer, Walter",
        "bankaccount_holder" : "Myer, Walter",
        "bankaccount_holder_extra" : false
    }
]
```

So the question is: How could I change the output-format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hash` utility class is what you need

```
$customers = Hash::extract($this->Customer->find('all'), '{n}.Customer');
/** ***/
$this->set('customers' , $customers);
$this->set('_serialize' , 'customers' );
```

Comment: Did not change anything

Comment: is it another ability to manipulate the format of json output ?

Comment: Can you post the hole controller action, that may help

Comment: Your answer was almost right. All I needed to change is to place the string instead of array in the `$this->set('_serialize' , 'customers');` . Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated the answer